# iOS - updating the media play/pause state in the multitasking bar

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, mpnowplayinginfocenter

We have a working app that uses an AU graph - CoreAudio API - to play audio. The graph is always running, and the play/pause state of the various source material is managed in the graph rendering callback functions.
We successfully respond to UIEventTypeRemoteControl events, and we successfully update the lock-screen with the meta-data for the currently playing content using MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.

The one missing piece is to update the state of the play/pause button in the iOS multitasking bar. It is always in the "pause" (||) mode, even when the app audio is already paused. It never switches to its "play" (>) state.

Which API is used to update the play/pause button state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out that when using a CoreAudio AU graph, [AUGraphStart()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AUGraphServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007289-CH7-SW36) will display the playback indicator in the iOS status bar and the iOS multitasking bar, and [AUGraphStop()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AUGraphServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007289-CH7-SW37) will clear them.

Comment: Same problem when using AVAudioPlayer, but it seems there is no way to get it work correctly.

Comment: @openfrog : Did u find any solution ??

Comment: Seeing the same problem. Is there any solution to it ?

Answer (score 3):

Change MPNowPlayingInfo dictionary, set new parameter

```
MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 1.0f to show pause button

MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate to 0.0f to show play button
```

From play button - to - pause button

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");
if(playingInfoCenter) {       
    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo];
    //[songInfo setObject:songTitle forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    //[songInfo setObject:songArtist forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;            
 }
```

From pause button - to - play button

```
Class playingInfoCenter = NSClassFromString(@"MPNowPlayingInfoCenter");
if(playingInfoCenter) {         
    NSMutableDictionary *songInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo];
    //[songInfo setObject:songTitle forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    //[songInfo setObject:songArtist forKey:MPMediaItemPropertyArtist];
    [songInfo setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f] forKey:MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate];
    [MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter].nowPlayingInfo = songInfo;
}
```

Comment: I'm using AVPlayer, and getting same error.  And I'm try your solution and it's work in simulator and not working in real device. Please help me out from this problem if u know any other solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is answer is correct in general,  but not with respect to the question. The question is with regards to the core audio API not working properly with  MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.